# JDBC + ScriptRunner : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jdbc

I code a class with a PostgreSQL JDBC driver and use the [ScriptRunner](https://gist.github.com/831762/) class to use an external .sql script file. It works like expected but there is an annoying java.lang.NullPointerException in the output. It appears as often as the number lines in the SQL file.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class ConnectPostgreSQL {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
  System.out.println("Checking if Driver is registered with DriverManager.");

  try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
    System.out.println("Let's print a stack trace, and exit.");
    cnfe.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }

  System.out.println("Registered the driver ok, so let's make a connection.");

  Connection c = null;

  try {
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "passroot");
  } catch (SQLException se) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
    se.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }
  System.out.println("Hooray! We connected to the PostgreSQL database!");

  long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println("==> Temps de départ : " + begin);

  ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(c, false, false);
  try {
    runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/ScriptSQL/create.sql")));
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println("==> Temps d'arrivée : " + end);

  float time = ((float) (end-begin)) / 1000f;
  System.out.println("Temps d'exécution : " + time + " sec");
  }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Checking if Driver is registered with DriverManager.
Registered the driver ok, so let's make a connection.
Hooray! We connected to the PostgreSQL database!
==> Temps de départ : 1300311132808
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:209)
    at ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:110)
    at ConnectPostgreSQL.main(ConnectPostgreSQL.java:36)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:209)
    at ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:110)
    at ConnectPostgreSQL.main(ConnectPostgreSQL.java:36)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:209)
    at ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:110)
    at ConnectPostgreSQL.main(ConnectPostgreSQL.java:36)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:209)
    at ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.java:110)
    at ConnectPostgreSQL.main(ConnectPostgreSQL.java:36)
CREATE TABLE TEST123(a INTEGER, b VARCHAR(50), c VARCHAR(50)) 
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(1, 'Riri', 'Tic') 
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(2, 'Fifi', 'Tac') 
INSERT INTO TEST123 VALUES(3, 'Loulou', 'Toc') 
==> Temps d'arrivée : 1300311132938
Temps d'exécution : 0.13 sec
```

I don't find how to get rid of these lines. :'(
Can somebody help me, please ?

Comment: make sure the file is accessible

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might a bug in the `ScriptRunner` thing. In line 209 it assumes `rs` is not null (though previously checking if `rs` is actually null). My change would be:

```
try {
   if (rs!=null) 
     rs.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
   if (statement!=null) 
      statement.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My guess would be that the problem does appear for statements like `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT`, while it doesn't for `SELECT`s. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, you're right ! The SELECT statement outputs nothing. I don't know if it's normal or not, I wish I could see the table content. :-/ So you think the best way to solve the problem is to apply this change ?

Comment: I tried your change. It solves the problem, thanks a lot ! Do you know if it's normal if I can't see the return of the SELECT statement ?